# unable to run mongodb at rasberry pi 4 with docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am not able to run a mongodb container at a rasberry pi 4.
cat /etc/os-release gives me this:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

unname -m gives me aarch64

I tried docker pull arm64v8/mongo
but this gives me
no matching manifest for linux/arm/v8 in the manifest list entries
then I tried https://hub.docker.com/r/alvarovalde/aarch64-mongodb
but with this image I got mongodb exited with code 159

Does somebody knows how to run mongodb with docker at rpi4?
I can also install another os